# Printing Prime Numbers within Boundries

Tags: python-2.7

I 'm trying to print out prime numbers in a range with bool structure.

```
def get_boundries_from_user():
    upper_boundary = input("Enter upper boundary please:\n")
    lower_boundary = input("Enter lower boundary please:\n")
    return upper_boundry,lower_boundary

def print_prime_numbers():
    upper_boundry,lower_boundry = get_boundries_from_user()
    upper_boundry += 1
    if (lower_boundary<0 or upper_boundary<0):
        print "Negative values cannot be prime numbers"
        return
    for i in range(lower_boundary,upper_boundary):
        prime = True
        for k in range(2,i):
            if (i%k==0):
                prime = False
                if prime:
                    print i

print_prime_numbers()
```

Where am I mistaken?Can you explain the logic of your answer along with it?

Comment: What input did you use to test your code? What's the output? 

Do you know the mathematical principle on which your code is based?

Comment: There is no output,just gets inputs and terminates.I know the principle it is already popular for beginneers :)

Comment: Which input did you use? Please edit your question to include the name of the mathematical principle so your question can be found!

Comment: Thank you for your intrerest hagello,it is very simple,when you look at codes carefuly,you can see,I think

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def get_boundries_from_user():
    upper_boundary = input("Enter upper boundary please:\n")
    lower_boundary = input("Enter lower boundary please:\n")
    return upper_boundary,lower_boundary

def print_prime_numbers():
    upper_boundry,lower_boundry = get_boundries_from_user()
    if (lower_boundry<0 or upper_boundry<0):
        print "Negative values cannot be prime numbers"
        return
    print "\nPrimes"
    for i in range(lower_boundry,upper_boundry+1):
        prime = True
        for k in range(2,i):
            if (i%k==0):
                prime = False
        if prime:
            print i

print_prime_numbers()
```

Here is the working code. Please note, you must enter upper boundary first and then the lower boundary. So for e.g UB-20 and LB-10 will give you output 
Primes
11
13
17
19

Comment: Thank you for your answer.But,do you know why it outputs the same number multiple times ?

Comment: that is because you print the 'i' in the inner loop. You should instead print it out of the inner loop. Look at the code i gave.